# Possible to programmatically decompile stored procedures using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When most of us want to see the definition of a SQL Server stored procedure, we fire up SSMS, find the object, right-click and select Modify or one of the other scripting options. This works fine, manually.

Some people also have the good fortune to get licensed for Redgate products that let you search, compare, and analyze the compiled database objects.

But supposing I would like to write desktop utilities that analyze stored procedures or other objects compiled on a SQL Server instance. There seems to be very little in the mainstream that is designed to accommodate that kind of software design.

So my question is: is it even possible, using C# and readily available NuGet packages, to connect to a SQL database and return the same DDL script that would be rendered into a query window using SSMS?

I know that there are lots of utilities already out there to cover almost anything I could want, but this is a programming question, not a request for a product recommendation.

Comment: I came across [TSql.Parser](https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser). You would still need to execute a query as described in John's answer to retrieve the procedure, but this might help you analyze it.

Comment: If memory serves, there is a sp_help that shows the text of a sproc

Comment: You can use SMO for that, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169330/simple-way-to-programmatically-get-all-stored-procedures

Comment: Almost, it is [`sp_helptext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a peek at the code via `sys.sql_modules`

**Example**

```
SELECT [schema_name] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) 
      ,[object_name] = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) 
      ,*
 FROM  sys.sql_modules
--WHERE  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) = 'dbo'
--  AND OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = '<<some store procedure or UDF>>'
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @Maxx Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_helptext 'sp_name'` for stored procedures. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql)

Comment: Interesting, this returns the script but with each row as a record. May be particularly useful in certain contexts.